# OrientDB - Client driver version is different than Server version

Tags: java, jboss, orientdb, graph-databases

I have installed latest version of OrientDB (2.2.18 GA Community Edition). I am trying to connect the Orient DB database from JBOSS.

Using latest OrientDB JDBC Driver 2.2.18 ALL for JDBC connection. But when trying to connect getting below error:-

```
> 06:04:14,279 INFO  [com.orientechnologies] (default task-6) OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=2,184MB (heap=3,641MB os=7,873MB disk=36,292MB)
06:04:14,377 WARNING [com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient] (default task-6) The Client driver version is different than Server version: client=32, server=36. You could not use the full features of the newer version. Assure to have the same versions on both
06:04:14,392 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /crl-api/rest/ping: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database url=remote:localhost:2424/crl-mgmt
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database url=remote:localhost:2424/crl-mgmt
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:282) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPolled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:140) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:340) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:313) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:154) [orientdb-graphdb-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:77) [orientdb-graphdb-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:128) [orientdb-graphdb-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.getTx(OrientGraphFactory.java:74) [orientdb-graphdb-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.core.CrlService._getOrientGraph(CrlService.java:94) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.core.CrlService.lookupQuery(CrlService.java:104) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.core.CrlService.query(CrlService.java:78) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.core.CrlService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.query(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.rest.CrlRest._queryJson(CrlRest.java:71) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.rest.CrlRest.queryJson(CrlRest.java:64) [classes:]
        at com.amadeus.crl.api.rest.CrlRest$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.queryJson(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageClusterConfiguration$STATUS.valueOf(OStorageClusterConfiguration.java:24) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration.fromStream(OStorageConfiguration.java:257) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration.load(OStorageConfiguration.java:132) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:225) [orientdb-client-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.open(OStorageRemoteThread.java:89) [orientdb-client-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:249) [orientdb-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        ... 54 more
```

The setup works fine with old orient DB version 2.1.2 but not working with the latest one.

Please help.

Comment: Check your dependencies because I can see in the log 2.1.2 as version of orientdb jars.

Comment: moreover, in your stacktrace  the JDBC api isn't used. It seems that your application accesses to  OrientDB via the graph API. MAybe you don't need the JDBC driver, but orientdb-graph.